# Confusion in Phase Shift Keying

Tags: digital-communications

What is the difference between Digital phase modulation(DPM) and Phase shift keying (PSK)? http://suraj.lums.edu.pk/zartash/publications/2007-DigitalPhaseMod.pdf It says that PSK is a special case of DP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phase shift keying is linear modulation.

Digital phase modulation is not necessarily linear.

Comment: Any chance to elaborate your answer?

Comment: I can elaborate depending on how clear the question is. Do you want the defition of linear modulation?

Comment: It's mostly to make it a good quality answer.

Comment: Thanks for opinion, but I don't think a longer answer gives more information because I believe the difference is just that. And to talk more about these definitions, the OP's paper is very clear. I will leave my answer here for a while to see if the OP and other members think it is ok; otherwise I will delete it and make it a comment.

Comment: Just curious, you downvoted because you think my answer needs to be detailed or you think it is simply totally wrong??